# protoc "tried to write file twice"

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm was to follow this https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10 . I realized part way through that I was running into problems because not all of my files in the protos folder were converted to python files?
So i tried to do each file separately again.

this is what i put into command prompt. it's telling me "tried to write file twice". and in the folder there is still no center_net_pb2.py file.

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research>protoc object_detection/protos/center_net.proto --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\center_net.proto
object_detection/protos/center_net_pb2.py: Tried to write the same file twice.
```

I'm using protobuf version 3.12.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included the input file name twice:

```
protoc object_detection/protos/center_net.proto --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\center_net.proto
```

Just put it in once:

```
protoc object_detection/protos/center_net.proto --python_out=.
```

Either backslashes or forward slashes work on Windows, so you can use either.

Comment: Some other post i saw send to do it that way. But this way makes more sense and it works so thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it! As the answer worked for you, please mark it accepted by clicking the tick next to it.